# Am I supposed to be able to fetch while an eventsource connection is open?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, server-sent-events

I'm playing with server-sent events for my web application in order to provide real-time updates to data that is shared among users.  I have it working with a little toy application that just increments a counter and reports the new count to the client every second.  The server-side `eventsource` logic then terminates after ten seconds.

After adding some additional functionality, I've run into an issue where other fetch requests from the client "hang" until the `eventsource` request has closed.  Is this the intended behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Here are a couple of network tab screenshots from DevTools (Chrome) that hopefully clarify the issue:

`_pwa_fetch_contents.php` "hung up" while `_sse_tests.php` loops and provides the `eventsource` data:
[image: Waiting for eventsource screenshot1]

`_pwa_fetch_contents.php` resolves and returns data after first termination of `_sse_tests.php`, before reconnecting to the `eventsource` handler:
[image: Waiting for eventsource screenshot2]

I'm using PHP on the server side, and I'm assuming this behavior has something to do with a fundamental misunderstanding on my part of the technologies involved.  As such, I don't really know what code to share.  Let me know what more I can do to illuminate the problem, and I'll edit the question with relevant code/screenshots.

Thanks :)

Comment: if your using sessions, i.e session_start() and dont session_write_close() it will hang.

Comment: Woof, looks like that was it.  I really don't get how sessions work with php; do you know of any good resources for helping grok the fundamentals of sessions in php?  I've done some diving into the PHP manual, but apparently I'm still not all the way there with my understanding of session behavior.

Comment: np, its a common one with sse's and multi ajax calls etc - default php sessions write to file, a long-running process prevents the end-of-file session write, so it blocks it to prevent concurrency issues.